# Using ADO.NET for a Data Access Layer in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, ado.net

I'm trying to roll a high performance DAL for my ASP.NET Core API. I want to use ADO.NET and I am having difficulty designing the software architecture. I'm looking for help discussing a good approach.

### What I Have

My codebase will consist of three projects

- MyApp.API
- MyApp.Repositories (data access layer)
- MyApp.Services (business logic)

I'll implement `IUnitOfWork` within `MyApp.Repositories` and create a concrete `SqlUnitOfWork` in `MyApp.API`. `Startup.cs` will register `IUnitOfWork` to `SqlUnitOfWork`. Later on, when I get more data sources (Mongo, etc.), I can incorporate a `UnitOfWorkFactory`.

### Questions

1. Should I register each repository in `Startup.cs` or simply add them as properties of `IUnitOfWork`? The thinking here is I would use Dependency Injection in my Controllers, Services and Repositories, but only have to inject `IUnitOfWork`.
2. How do I pass my connection string into the `SqlUnitOfWork`? I know the connection string should stay within `MyApp.API`.

Comment: If `SqlUnitOfWork` were added in startup as a service, you can inject the context. you can also inject `IConfiguration` to access the connection string if you need it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer is irrelevant because it is suggesting I use EF, which I want to avoid.

I implemented Dapper with a repository pattern. I did not use a unit of work because I concluded to would lead to performance loses I did not want to have.

Here is a raw prototype I implemented.
https://github.com/lenardchristopher/AdoAspDotNetCoreTest

Comment: Hola, y encontraste algún modelo de conexión con ADO.NET? El el link que nos compartes observo que utilizan Dapper. Que tal te fue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are working with aspnet-core thus using [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) as your ORM will work in this situation.

I agree with you on registering your repositories as part of `IUnitOfWork` then adding it as a service to your DI container which you will then inject in your controllers.

To answer your second question, let's assume that your `SqlUnitOfWork` implementation has a constructor that receives a `DbContext` instance.

> In ASP.NET Core, the `DbContext` is added to the DI container and thus
>   any other service that requires or has a dependency on DbContext in
>   it's constructor, it will automatically be resolved by the DI
>   container.

First remember to have your connection string defined in `appsettings.json` as so.

[image]

Then now lets use that connection string to add a `DbContext` object to our DI container and a little [Futher reading on Configuring DbContext in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")));
}
```

After that, registering other services to our DI container that need our context will be very easy since the container will resolve that dependency for us.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, SqlUnitOfWork>();
}
```

Hope this answers your questions. If not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I am specifically trying to not use Entity Framework. I want to used ADO.NET (or Dapper) because performance the primary focus of my app. So, how would I create an ADO.NET version of an dbContext and pass it to `SqlUnitOfWork`?

Comment: It sounds like from the OP they don't want to use EF in favor of their own implementation wrapping ADO.Net. Also, EF is *already* a repository/UoW so recommending additional classes/abstractions/layers for that purpose is incredibly redundant